# Detect all clicks from within a WinForms MainMenu Control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to log all clicks in a MainMenu control I am using in a C# WinForms application. The menu system in place is very extensive and some of it is generated on the fly. I am looking for a way to add something directly to MainMenu that will get me the MenuItem object when it is clicked.

I have used Application.AddMessageFilter to catch all clicks in the rest of the application but it seems that the MainMenu control somehow gets around being tracked in this way.

Comment: Sounds really simple to me. In the MenuItem click events, pass the e.Buttons clicks to your datastore of mouse clicks.

Comment: The menu is generated dynamical in several different places, I am looking for something that I can add once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need something that is global, have a look at http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/

> This library allows you to tap keyboard and mouse and to detect and
>   record their activity even when an application is inactive and runs in
>   background.

I'm not sure if I would do this in my applications, they certainly wouldn't pass 'clean' software tests by auditors but perhaps your application is company internal and capturing this 'particular/single' applications keystrokes and mouse movements would satisfy security requirements.

Comment: Sorry but I am under strict orders to only capture what is happening in this MainMenu control, nothing more.

Comment: @JustinDoesWork why did you write "I have used Application.AddMessageFilter to catch all clicks in the rest of the application"?

Comment: That functionality is done and works correctly in all other situations but this one. My task now is to just fix this one issue.

Comment: @JustinDoesWork Ok, well if you dynamically add menu's obviously you have to assign an EventHandler for the click event. So have one main Menu_ClickEvent and trap the clicks in there, then pass the e.Buttons clicks to your datastore of mouse clicks.